# Derivative of a vector expression (tensor product?)

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-spaces, tensors

I am trying to get the derivative of a vector expression.

$$\vec{x} = \vec{g} - (\vec{g}\cdot\hat{\tau})\hat{\tau}$$

Where $\vec{g}$ is a vector and $\hat{\tau}$ is a unit vector both defined in an N-dimensional space. Now, if I understand correctly, to get the derivative of a vector, I need to get the outer product of the del operator with the vector. From some equations that I collected from questionable sources, I have been able to get the following expression:

$$\begin{align} \vec{\nabla}\otimes\vec{x} &= \vec{\nabla}\otimes\vec{g} - \hat{\tau}\otimes \vec{\nabla}\otimes (\vec{g}\cdot\hat{\tau}) - [ (\vec{g}\cdot\hat{\tau})(\vec{\nabla}\otimes\hat{\tau})]^T \\ \\\\
 &= \vec{\nabla}\otimes\vec{g} - \hat{\tau}\otimes[(\vec{\nabla}\otimes\vec{g})^T \hat{\tau} + (\vec{\nabla}\otimes\hat{\tau})^T \vec{g})] - [ (\vec{g}\cdot\hat{\tau})(\vec{\nabla}\otimes\hat{\tau})]^T \end{align}$$

This works for me as I can calculate the derivative of each vector. Problem is, I am completely unfamiliar with vector, tensor etc. and I don't know if the above expression is correct. (Full disclosue, the $\vec{g}$ vector is the gradient of a scalar function, and the expression above projects out the component of the gradient along a certain direction. I need to calculate the Hessian matrix for this expression as well, which is what I am trying to do).

**Could someone familiar with tensor and vector algebra please check if the above derivation is correct**, and furthermore, **let me know a reference book or resource which I can cite for these types of mathematic operations** (i.e. expression for derivative of a scalar function multiplied by vector function, or derivative of dot product of two vector functions)?

Comment: What are the variables in your problem?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: The derivative is defined for a map $f : E \to F$. What is $E$ in your case? And also $f$ by the way?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net All the vectors (g and tau) are defined on a N-dimensional space (x_1, x_2, x_3 ..., x_n). g is the gradient vector of a scalar function f. The scalar function f does not have any analytic expression, but its gradient and Hessian are available. Is that what you meant?